# SQLite 3 database not being read properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I had to create a sqlite3 database in my rails 3.1.1 app manually, converting from a mysql database using the [mysql2sqlite](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=150476) tool, and then running:

```
sqlite3 development.sqlite3 < mysql2sqlite_dump.sql
```

Anyways, the `development.sqlite3` file is there, and the server starts up fine and all the pages are loading fine (no database errors about missing tables or anything), but the data isn't being read... just as if it wasn't there. Even running `Event.all`, for example, in console gives me :

```
  Event Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" 
 => []
```

When there should actually be several events. Looking in the `sqlite3` file, I can see that all the information is there, but it's just not being read. I will post part of the database file if anybody requests it.

My question is: Why isn't the database being read properly, and how can I make it so?

Thanks.

Comment: So if you `sqlite3 development.sqlite3` then you can select from the tables and everything is there, right? Are you sure Rails is using your `development.sqlite3` file rather than something other SQLite database file?

Comment: Running `select * from events;` in the sqlite3 console returns nothing. My `database.yml` file is pointing at `db/development.sqlite3`.

Comment: Hmm. Does `select * from sqlite_master` tell you anything illuminating?

Comment: That script looks a few years out of date, how many tables do you have to transfer? Might be easier to use `mysqldump --compatible=ansi --complete-insert --compact`, patch up the types in the CREATE TABLEs by hand, and then feed it straight into `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I seemed to have solved the problem. The issue was that `mysqldump` (being executed inside of the `mysql2sqlite` script) was dropping and then creating the tables (which is default), and that was conflicting with the schema file. So, I created the database according the schema file, and then ran the script again with the `--no-create-info` option added for `mysqldump` so that it would only insert the information.

Thanks for the help everybody!